# How could I filter out the branch that commit wasn't committed to?

Tags: git

I have created a branch `test` from `master`. Now `git branch --contains $commitid` for the commit to the `master` performed before the creation of the branch `test` shows that it belongs both to the `master` and the `test`:

```
git on  master [⇣?] 
❯ git log --oneline --all --graph
* f56a18a (tag: 0.12, origin/master) added 8
* 6eb3856 added 6
* a12dfb2 (HEAD -> master, tag: 0.11) added 6
* eff5df4 added 4
| * acf20e2 (origin/test) added 7
| * 86ec659 (test) added 5
|/  
| * a5d72eb (tag: 0.10) added 3
| * 84eded8 (tag: 0.9) added 3
|/  
* a449cf1 (tag: 0.8) added 3
* 9bf71a6 (tag: 0.7) added 3
* 2c9d219 (tag: 0.6) added 3
* 85bdd34 (tag: 0.5) added 3
* 26f2cd0 (tag: 0.4) added 3
* 52bd26a (tag: 0.3) added 3
* 5bfaece (tag: 0.2) added 3
* 2eef64e (tag: 0.1) added 3
* 3ee667e (tag: 0.0) added 3

git on  master [⇣?] 
❯ git branch --contains 3ee667e
* master
  test
```

Is there any way to filter out the branch the change was not committed to when doing `git branch --contains`?

Comment: Despite the metaphor, changes are just not committed *to branches*. git doesn't store that metadata.

Comment: Git has no way of knowing which branch you were on when you did the commit. That commit belongs to both branches.

Comment: A commit isn't tied to any particular branch. The only question you can answer is if a commit is reachable from a branch, and in your case the commit you're asking about is reachable from both master and your test branch. With this knowledge, it might make more sense to rewrite your question to be "list all commits that are reachable from test that aren't also reachable from master".

Comment: Might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ to learn what Git is, what a commit is, what a branch is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that isn't how Git works. The name of the branch is not part of the commit, this information isn't retained anywhere.